# react router parameter loading index route only

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I have my routes defines as follows:

```
    <Route path="/manage" component={Manage}>
      <IndexRoute component={Manage}></IndexRoute>
      <Route path=":id" component={Edit}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Route>
```

Now when I click on a button in my `Manage` component I call following function:

```
   handleEditClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let selectedId= this.state.selectedId;
        this.props.router.replace("/manage/" + selectedId); 
    },
```

My browser does display me the correct link but my component is not loaded as should. It only renders me the `Manage` component and not the `Edit` component.

Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE**

changing the child route to `<Route path="/manage/:id" component={Edit}></Route>` also loads me the `Manage` component

**UPDATE 2**

if I do not use child routes but in stead create them on the same level, the `Edit` component does render, but I'd like to use child routes.

Comment: do you have a this.props.children on Manage compnent?

Comment: No, what do you mean with this exactly?

Answer (score 0):

On your render() you need a {this.props.children} ... it's where React router knows where to put child Component

In your routes

```
<Route path="/manage" component={Manage}>
  <IndexRoute component={Manage}></IndexRoute>
  <Route path=":id" component={Edit}></Route>
</Route>
```

If you navigate to `/manage/:id`, React Router renders Manager and Edit components... but where to put Edit? 
So

you need to have something like this.

```
class Manager extends Component {
   render(){
     return (
       <div>
          Hello
          {this.props.children}
       </div>
     );
   }
}
```

So React Router knows to put Edit along side when you go to `/manage/:id`

```
<div>
   Hello
   <Edit />
</div>
```